# Android - different image for rollover on ImageButton

Tags: android, imagebutton

Is it possible to specify a different image when the user's focus comes to an ImageButton? I want to display an image button on a LinearLayout and change the image when the user's focus comes on the button or when the user presses the button.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  What you need is a drawable xml file that defines a selector.

```
<selector xmlns:android...
  <item android:state_enabled="false" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="..." />
  <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="false" android:drawable="..." />
</selector>
```

Then, use the id of this drawable XML when specifying the ImageButton in your layout XML.

Comment: Do not just copy and paste it. Nate just gave the code needed to declare one.

Answer (score 0):

The precedent answer did not work for me. Here is the code I found somewhere else:

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
         <item android:drawable="@drawable/refresh_pushed" android:state_pressed="true" />
         <item android:drawable="@drawable/refresh" />
    </selector>
```

You can also add a state for foccussed objects by adding a line and using:

> android:state_focused="true"