# Android imagebutton how to change icon size

Tags: android, icons, imagebutton

I have been working on interfaces lately and I have many problems with imagebutton sizes. I'm very bad at designing stuff and I'm having major problems with the Android Icons. Thus, I have some questions regarding those.

First of all this is my current layout:

[image]

As you can see, I have two icons that have different sizes and that's not good. I can't seem to force them to take the same size.

My questions are:

1 - How do I force them to take the same size?

2 - What are the recommended size differences for hdpi, ldpi,mdpi and xhdpi?

3 - Why, if I set the imageButton background color to the same color as the layout background, the Icon is moved as if there was no button in the background?

Example: [image]

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For these ImageButtons set the images using (instead of src):

```
android:background="@drawable/image_name"
```

Next thing is set:

```
android:layout_height="10dp" //or any size required
android:layout_width="10dp" //or any size required ... let these 2 sizes be same for both the ImageButtons
```

"dp" or "dip" is device independent pixels. The android system will take care of the resizing for different screen resolutions

Also, a better thing to do would be to set-up hover images for your button separately.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to do the trick with this! although, what do you mean by set-up hover images?

Comment: Glad I was able to help :) When the user presses the button / when the button is in the "pressed" state - A hover image will be displayed indicating the button press. For more on how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/q/606694/735675

Answer (score 8):

Instead of replacing android:src with android:background you can use android:scaleType attribute and set it to "fitXY".

see: [Android - Image Button Scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24155422/android-image-button-scale)

Comment: thanks, to mantain icon proportions I used: `android:scaleType="centerInside"`

Answer (score 1):

type this:

in java:

```
YOUR_VIEW.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width,height));
```

or in XML:

```
android:layout_height="10px"
android:layout_width="10px"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
android:layout_height="10dp"

android:layout_width="10dp"
```

Dont keep in `px`, always you have to keep in only `dp`

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have said, set the button sizes using dp or dip in the layout xml files.

For handling different screen sizes see this doc: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html