# Android - Image Button Scale

Tags: android, image, user-interface

I am trying to fit an image inside an `ImageButton` for testing but the way the `ImageButton`behaves is not as expected.

initially, I made a **988x89** pixels **PNG** image and placed it inside an `ImageButton`, which is in a 7inches **1024x600** pixels emulated screen. The `ImageButton`is **988dp x 89dp**, I know dp is not the same as pixels, but for this resolution I expected the image to scale itself reasonably to occupy most of the `ImageButton`. Also I changed to px instead of dp for testing and it made no difference.

But instead the `ImageButton` made the image inside it VERY small (the blue lines are the `ImageButton` bounds and the green line is a center align indication).

[image: Test Image 1]

so **question #1: Why does the `ImageButton` make an image as big as this so small, when it could fill most of the screen, even with the `ImageButton` size being very wide?**

So to overcome this, I selected `adjustViewBounds` which made no difference, at all, which brings question #2: **Why? Isn't the adjust view bounds supposed to adjust the view bounds?**

> The code so far is:

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="988dp"
        android:layout_height="89dp"
        android:id="@+id/ibTest"
        android:src="@drawable/image_top_test"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hlTopBar"
        android:background="#00000000" />
```

So later I changed `scaleType` to `fitCenter` and the image became:

[image: Test Image 2]

Which is weird for me as well, since the `ImageButton` has the same aspect ratio as the image, so I would expect it to fit 100%, but it's not fitting (there is a gap in the width in both sides of the image).

So later I changed `scaleType` to `fitXY` and I got my final result:

[image]

Which appears to be the expected image after all (comparing the image by `fitXY` to the image of `fitCenter` in Photoshop shows that the `fitCenter` image is slightly oval, but it can't be shown here, which is expected since the width isn't matching the image as the height does).

**So my general question is (#3): What's the right way for fitting an Image in Android, and to expect it to have it's regular size in the screen, and why is the scaling so messy and am I doing it wrong?**

I know there are screen sizes issues and dp and etc. but the scaling isn't behaving in a controlled way, `fitCenter` makes the image oval, and `fitXY` is too much dependent of me setting the right image ratio on XY, so I wonder if I am making something wrong and how it's supposed to be the right way.

> Final XML code:

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="988dp"
        android:layout_height="89dp"
        android:id="@+id/ibTest"
        android:src="@drawable/image_top_test"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hlTopBar"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html go through this

Comment: @kaushik I saw this documentation before, but `fitCenter` was supposed to make the image fit nicelly in the `ImageButton` according to this documentation....the width and height are the same as the image size, so how come it doesn't fit?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

That's a good try, you are trying to go deeper into the android implementations.

**Ans #3:**

At first providing exact size as height and width is not a good practice in android. If you wish to know why, the reason would be simply it will try to squeeze/expand the image to the size specified by you in the height and width params. Always *`wrap_content`* is the preferred Parameter so that the OS will automatically adjust depending upon the screen size.Hence you  need to modify as:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ibTest"
    android:src="@drawable/image_top_test"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/hlTopBar"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

**Ans #1 :**

Why does the ImageButton make an image as big as this so small, when it could fill most of the screen, even with the ImageButton size being very wide?

The answer is is similar to the above mentioned. Your Image size will be much lesser than that the Android OS calculated depending on your mentioned size, taking device resolution into consideration. Use the http://coh.io/adpi/ (or http://density.brdrck.me/) site to make it simple to calculate. Always take the mdpi as standard or base. Suppose your image size is 988X89 in mdpi, it will be:

[image] Now, it is as if you are trying to view an image of 988px X 89px on an xhdpi screen where the Android Os calculated the image size as 1976px X 178px, which is way larger than your given image size of 988px X 89px. that's why you get small image with most area white.

**How to correct it?**
Go through the Android specifications to support different densities screens. this requires you to design images specifically for hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi and put them in appropriate folders of:

```
 MyProject/
     res/
       drawable-xhdpi/
           awesomeimage.png
       drawable-hdpi/
           awesomeimage.png
       drawable-mdpi/
           awesomeimage.png
       drawable-ldpi/
           awesomeimage.png
```

Ref : http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html for more details

Comment: I was using `wrap_content` at first but the `ImageButton` was really small, just about the size of the small image inside it. I am making this app as a test for a specific tablet so I am not concerned about other screen sizes, I just wanted to have the exact image size for that particular screen. My initial objective was to use `wrap_content` and have the `ImageButton` being the same size as the image is supposed to have and just deal with the relative layout to do the positioning and centralization.

Comment: So just to be clear, in order to do it, I need to place the right scaled image in the folder that corresponds the screen density?

Comment: Exactly. As you said you are targetting tabs. You need to add on Images in  drawable-xhdpi/ folder. Also make sure your image is designed as per the calculation in the  http://coh.io/adpi/ site.

Comment: Ok, I will try it tomorrow and see how it goes...I just double checked and I placed all the images in the drawable-xxhdpi, so that's why it's so small right?

Comment: I have  a xxhdpi folder in Android Studio, but the calculator and the Android documentation doesn't have the xxhdpi measures, I wonder how much it is...

Comment: I've not designed apps for tab;ets. but can guide you to the following android developer site link http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/11/designing-for-tablets-were-here-to-help.html. Hope that helps you.

Comment: I said I was tagetting tabs? (I am doing a tab application, I just can't find where I mentioned it in here)

Comment: OH I guess you mean tab as tablet haha I thought about a Tab app like a TabHost... :D

Comment: Ok, I just tested it and it worked perfectly, I set it to `wrap_content` and not scaling and palced the images in the right folder and everything looks as it should! Many thanks!

Comment: That resolution calculator link is broken now.